# How to install xfce4-windowck-plugin in xubuntu16.04? (xfce 4.12)

Tags: xfce, window-manager

I can't found any package for xfce4-windowck-plugin in xubuntu 16.04.

This one don't work for me (64bits):http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/window-titlebar-buttons-on-panel-xfce4/

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~oiteam/+archive/ubuntu/xfce4) **Published in** section.

As you see this PPA is only available on Vivid (Ubuntu 15.04).

So can't add this PPA , and then install xfce4-windowck-plugin package **normally**.

But you can add a Vivid release of this PPA , **with your own risk** with this commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oiteam/xfce4
sudo sed -i 's/xenial/vivid/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oiteam-ubuntu-xfce4-xenial.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xfce4-windowck-plugin
```

Comment: `'This PPA does not support xenial'
Cannot add PPA: ''This PPA does not support xenial''.`

Comment: `sed: can't read /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oiteam-ubuntu-xfce4-xenial.list: No such file or directory
`